# Is there a Vim command to delete all fold markers in a file?

Tags: vim

To delete a particular fold one can do `zd`.

To delete all fold markers one can execute:

```
:%s/# {{{//
:%s/# }}}//
```

But is there a command (like `zd`) to delete all markers?

Comment: You could have just looked up `:h zd`, the answer is right there.

Comment: Funny how some people rather formulate an entire question than reading a bit around in the documentation.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for the annoyance. Select all the file visually before typing `zd` is the answer. I miss the obvious.

Comment: Please consider closing the question, or better write here the answer by yourself.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

tl;dr `zE` is the command you are looking for.

Now for the long version.

Assuming:

1. Your `foldmethod` is set to `marker`.
2. Your `foldmarker` setting matches the fold markers in the file
   (in your case it's the default `{{{,}}}`).
3. Your `commentstring` is set properly (this is almost certainly the case, unless vIM doesn't have a syntax file for the file type).

You can just use `zE` which **E**liminates all folds in the file.

You can check the settings by running `:set foldmethod? foldmarker? commentstring?` and set them by running `:set foldmethod=manual foldmarker={{{,}}} commentstring=#%s`.

See the docs here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#zE

There are some caveats in the docs here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#fold-delete-marker

> This does not work properly when:
>
> - A line contains more than one marker and one of them specifies a level.   Only the first one is removed, without checking if this will
>     have the   desired effect of deleting the fold.
> - The marker contains a level number and is used to start or end several folds   at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

I answer this myself:

To delete all fold markers, visually select all the file with `ggVG` before doing a `zd`.